# Unexplained error message: Doctrine\ORM version 2.14.1, PHP 8.2, Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException

Tags: doctrine-orm, annotations, fatal-error

I have several Entites with the annotation @ORM\HasLifeCycleCallbacks(), since I work with Doctrine ORM version 2.14.1 and PHP 8.2 I get the following message again and again:

[23-Mar-2023 10:33:22 Europe/Zurich] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\prePersist" in method Webdreams\Service\Entities\Document::setCreatedAt() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation? in /home/qowimyky/public_html/apps/wdv-512/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php:36

In the past, the PrePersist and PreFlush always worked, and I did not change anything in the code.

It is also strange that when I execute the use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM function in a script explicitly flown by new ORM\PrePersist() and new ORM\PreFlush(), no messages are displayed for some time.

This is one of my Entities:

```
namespace Webdreams\Service\Entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM,
    Webdreams\Extensions\Doctrine\ORM\Util
;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Webdreams\Service\Repositories\DocumentRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Table(name="documents", options={"charset":"utf8mb4", "collate":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"})
 */
class Document
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $updatedAt;

    .......

    /**
     * @ORM\prePersist
     */
    public function setCreatedAt()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
    }
}
```

Is this a bug in Doctrine\ORM or PHP ? Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks a lot for your help.

So now i have changed

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/*
 * @ORM/HasLIfecycleCallbacks()
 */
```

to

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM,
    Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\HasLifecycleCallbacks
;
/*
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
```

and then it works.....but why ?
it is very confusing, because the same installation runs perfectly on another server without errors

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's because of your Doctrine or PHP migration, it looks like your annotations are now case sensitive. You then have to use @ORM\PrePersist instead of @ORM\prePersist

Comment: Thank you very much, I have changed it, and until now it works :-). What I don't understand is that it has worked for years, and since I upgraded Doctrine to 2.14.1 I only have the error intermittently, is it possible that it has to do with the newly installed Symfony Cache Adatper?

Comment: @Peter Maybe you also changed your OS in the meantime? This is a known problem when switching from a case-insensitive to a case-sensitive environment (i.e. DEV to PROD environment).